# How to install macOS back after installing Fedora?

Tags: macos, install, unix

I installed Fedora on macbook by wiping macOS, now I want to install macOS back, how can I do this? Before wiping I made a full backup of macos installer, but how to use it, I couldn't able to figure out.

I know how to do it from macbook with `createinstallmedia` command, but I don't have another macbook nor my friends have. What's the solution now?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) In order to help you we'll need to know what exact model of MacBook you have? Depending on your model you'll have a range of options. Also, which macOS installer did you make a backup of? Finally, while you don't have access to another Mac, can we assume you would have access to a PC?

Comment: @Monomeeth I've `Macbook Air mid 2013`. I made backup of `macOS Sierra`. Here is the content of that backup folder https://dpaste.de/4P9P.

Yes I've access to Linux PC.

Comment: Okay, so do you know if you still have a recovery partition on your drive?

Comment: No I don't have offline recovery partition, I'd deleted that all.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don’t have a recovery partition, the first thing I’d recommend is trying to install macOS from Internet Recovery.

Your model of MacBook Air should be able to boot directly from an internet connection. First you need to be somewhere where you will be able to access the internet - however this works best with Wi-Fi networks using WEP and WPA security.

Follow these steps:

1. Ensure your MacBook Air is fully powered off
2. Hold down the <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keys and press the <kbd>Power</kbd> button
3. Keep holding down the keys until you see a spinning globe with the message *Starting Internet Recovery*
4. Soon you’ll see a progress bar - be patient as this may take a while
5. Eventually the OS X Utilities screen will appear
6. Click Reinstall OS X
7. Follow the prompts

If for some reason this doesn’t work, let me know.

Comment: I guess it'll work but I don't have that much time, my internet connection is slow, so as I have backup can I use that any way?

Comment: Well, the thing is that you will need to make a bootable USB drive from your backed up installer. And, to do that you'll need another Mac or access to a PC. If you had access to another Mac it'd be fairly quick to do, with a PC it'll be more involved. So, my assumption is that while this process will take some time, it may not take any longer than it would for you to make a bootable USB drive.

Comment: It'll take more than one day because my internet speed is 250kB/s, that's why I don't want go that route. What are the steps for Windows PC? I can have Windows PC.

Comment: Read [How to quickly create a macOS bootable USB on Windows](http://pureinfotech.com/create-macos-bootable-usb-windows/) for one of the easiest ways to do it on Windows. I would recommend you read the whole thing first, just to familiarise yourself with what's required before you start.

Comment: I don't have DMG image, so I think I need to install it with internet recovery.

Thank you.